# Google API 2.0 PHP Server to Server cannot upload file to Google Drive

Tags: php, drive

I am trying to upload image from my website to my Google Drive using Google API 2.0 (PHP Version). When I tried the code below, no error reported on the webpage but my photo wasn't being uploaded. Can some one please help me with problem? I apprecitated about it.

```
require_once realpath('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('vendor/MyProject.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
// This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$result = $service->files->create(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents('1.jpeg'),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    )
);
?>
```